# Angular2 dynamically access this object typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular2 typescript component I have the following local variables

```
teapot10: boolean = false;
teapot20: boolean = false;
teapot30: boolean = false;
```

I want to use these dynamically in a function like so

```
doSomeStuff("teapot20")

doSomeStuff(teapot: string){
    this[teapot] = true
}
```

So in this example I pass the string name of the local variable "teapot20" and I want to use this string to manipulate the actual variable called teapot20.

Can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the dot, should be: `this[teapot]`

Comment: Do you mean `this[teapot]`  ?

Comment: thats a typo... thats what i used but doesn't work

Comment: it does work!! I was using the wrong variable in my code... arse

Answer (score 1):

You better use [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) instead of just a string:

```
doSomeStuff(teapot: "teapot10" | "teapot20" | "teapot30") {
    this[teapot] = true
}
```

Or:

```
type PropNames = "teapot10" | "teapot20" | "teapot30";
doSomeStuff(teapot: PropNames) {
    this[teapot] = true
}
```

This way you can make sure that no one calls it like so:

```
doSomeStuff("tepo10");
```